# opencv image update in gtk for video streaming linux with C programming

Tags: gtk, opencv

I am using opencv 1.0.0 and gtk2.0. I want to grab images continuously from a video stream. So far I have successfully been able to grab still image. This is non standard IP camera not VGA/USB /V4L one so need to know explicit method to refresh or update images continuously for video streaming!

```
GtkWidget *image;

...
...

IplImage*   bayerImage = NULL;
IplImage*   rgbImage = NULL;

...
...
...

cvCvtColor( bayerImage, rgbImage, CV_BayerBG2RGB );
// Usually opencv image is BGR, so we need to change it to RGB

pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ((guchar*)rgbImage->imageData,
                 GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,
                 FALSE,
                rgbImage->depth,
                rgbImage->width,
                rgbImage->height,
                 (rgbImage->widthStep),
                  NULL,
                  NULL);
image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (pix);
```

Comment: You're asking us how to control a camera we know nothing about, and didn't bother to mention the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* (c) 2010 Virgoptrex. Feel Free to use. Leave credits intact */

#include gtk/gtk.h

gint t=0;

     gboolean
     expose_event_callback (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data)
     {


     //g_object_ref_sink (widget->window);

     // gdk_drawable_ref (widget->window);

       gdk_draw_arc (widget->window,
                     widget->style->fg_gc[GTK_WIDGET_STATE (widget)],
                     TRUE,
                     0, 0, widget->allocation.width, widget->allocation.height,
                     0, 64 * 18*t);

      //gdk_drawable_unref (widget->window);



       return TRUE;
     }



static gboolean
time_handler(GtkWidget *widget)
{    


 gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(widget));

  if (t<20)
  { t++; }
  else if (t >=20)
  { t=0; } 

 printf("hello %d\n",t);
   return TRUE;


} 

int main( int argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *aspect_frame;
    GtkWidget *drawing_area;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);



    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Aspect Frame");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                  G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    /* Create an aspect_frame and add it to our toplevel window */

    aspect_frame = gtk_aspect_frame_new ("2x1", /* label */
                                         0.5, /* center x */
                                         0.5, /* center y */
                                         2, /* xsize/ysize = 2 */
                                         FALSE /* ignore child's aspect */);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), aspect_frame);
    gtk_widget_show (aspect_frame);

    /* Now add a child widget to the aspect frame */

    drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new ();

    /* Ask for a 200x200 window, but the AspectFrame will give us a 200x100
     * window since we are forcing a 2x1 aspect ratio */
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (drawing_area, 200, 200);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (aspect_frame), drawing_area);
    gtk_widget_show (drawing_area);

     g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (drawing_area), "expose_event",
                         G_CALLBACK (expose_event_callback), NULL);

    g_timeout_add(100, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer)drawing_area);


    gtk_widget_show (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```